# DataList in ASP.Net Video should be enlarge onclick

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net, .net

**WebSiteVideo.aspx**

```
     <asp:DataList ID="DataList1" Visible="true" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" RepeatColumns="1" CellSpacing="15">
     <ItemTemplate>
           <a class="player" style="height: 100px; width: 120px; display: block" href='<%# Eval("Id", "File.ashx?Id={0}") %>'>
            </a>
            <u>
                <%# Eval("Name") %>
            </u>
     </ItemTemplate>
     </asp:DataList>
```

when i am clicking the video it should be Enlarge, According to this coding what have to do? Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

You have to probably call some kind of function through client side which will zoom your video.

Check this [JQuery Show Large Image Preview When Hover On Link In Asp.Net](http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2012/09/show-large-image-preview-when-hover-on.html)